# USB AC WiFi Dongle (rtl8812au drivers) not working for linux 18.04 on my embedded PC

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

Using an [UNO1372GH](https://www.advantech.com/products/gf-bvl2/uno-1372gh/mod_9b1e793f-c70e-4f5d-a089-e4815c3512de) and [ASUS USB-AC56R](https://www.asus.com/Networking/USBAC56R/HelpDesk/). Had no problem using the adapter when win10 was installed, but having trouble with drivers for Linux 18.04.4 LTS.

This PC does NOT have secure boot (it is not even an option).

First I downloaded and attempted to make the official drivers from ASUS support site, but they failed to make (seems to be a common issue).

Then I tried to download [the abperisamy drivers](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux). These compiled successfully, but when I use modprobe and reboot, the Wi-Fi dongle is still not detected.

I also tried the latest from the repo: sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms.
This also installed fine, but still not detected.

Checking dmesg, I get:

```
iws-ts-001@iwsts001-UNO-1372G-E3AE:~$ dmesg | grep RTL871X
[  218.658179] RTL871X: module init start
[  218.658184] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902
[  218.658185] RTL871X: build time: Jul 27 2020 19:18:34
[  218.658266] RTL871X: module init ret=0
[  221.186675] RTL871X: module exit start
[  221.186750] RTL871X: module exit success
[  221.330052] RTL871X: module init start
[  221.330055] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902
[  221.330057] RTL871X: build time: Jul 27 2020 19:18:34
[  221.330130] RTL871X: module init ret=0
```

Using `lshw -c network` only returns my ethernet adapters, and `iw list`  returns nothing.

Also tried:

```
lsmod | grep 8812
8812au               1290240  0
cfg80211              712704  1 8812au
```

My usb list:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I seem to have installed both rtl8812au

```
sudo modinfo rtl8812au
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8812au.ko
version:        v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     563D0DCC21D421BB16893BF
alias:          usb:v2357p011Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v3823p6249d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v056Ep400Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v056Ep4007d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p029Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p025Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0242d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0023d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3318d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3314d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0953d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA813d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0823d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0820d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp9097d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0122d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0115d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p805Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3316d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB30d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1058p0632d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3426d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0409p0408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0952d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2604p0012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1109d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           rtl8812au
vermagic:       5.4.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_special_rf_path:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_led_enable:Enable status LED (int)
parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_dml:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_RFE_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_OffEfuseMask:default open Efuse Mask vaule:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_FileMaskEfuse:default drv Mask Efuse vaule:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
```

and 8812au:

```
sudo modinfo 8812au
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko
version:        v4.3.8_12175.20140902
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     A1B4B8FF70567B29CF1C971
alias:          usb:v056Ep4007d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0242d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0023d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3318d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3314d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0953d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA813d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0820d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p025Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p805Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3316d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB30d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp9097d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1058p0632d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3426d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0409p0408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0952d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1109d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           8812au
vermagic:       5.4.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_special_rf_path:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable, 2:auto (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
parm:           rtw_nhm_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_RFE_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
```

Neither of which seem to work. I have scoured the forums and no solutions seem to work for me.
Praying that someone (paging chili555) will save me from my networking driver nightmare!

Edit: Whoops, accidentally didn't have dongle plugged in when I ran lsusb. Here is the output with it plugged in.

```
iws-ts-001@iwsts001-UNO-1372G-E3AE:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b05:17d2 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else having this issue,the following solution worked for me.

Download the [latest drivers from aircrack-ng](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/tree/v5.7.0). You can either download the zip and extract or use git clone. If you use git clone, remember to checkout to the latest branch (currently v5.7.0 at time of writing).

Follow the install instructions in the git read.me using dkms.
Once install is complete enter

```
sudo modprobe -v 88XXau
```

then

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Comment: chili555 says voted up!